# Accessing and storing a bit from a uint8

Tags: c, embedded

I need to access a particular bit from a `uint8` variable, and store this bit value to another `uint8` variable. Right now I am doing the following to achieve this:

```
bit_value = (uint8_variable & (1 << BIT_POSITION)) >> BIT_POSITION;
```

Is this the right method? If it is right, is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Update: 
One more question. I need to set a particular bit in a uint8 to a value X(not toggling the bit).
eg: In 1100 0101, I need to set bit 2 to X, without modifying the other bits - to obtain 1100 0X01.
I have been racking my brain, but I can't land on a straight forward solution.

Comment: Do you need the actual bit (eg, cast to bit 1 or 0), or just know if it's set or not?

Comment: bit_value = ((uint8_variable>>BIT_POSITION)&1)

Comment: You are near the solution. Miss just a bit mask as suggested by user43648

Comment: @Jeroen3 i need the actual bit value..

Comment: I am still not sure what you want. Should value "10100100" and bit position "2" return "1" or "4"?

Comment: @Rev1.0 It should return a "1"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got an idea, at least I would do it like this. So,
 `bit_value = ((uint8_variable>>BIT_NEEDED)&1)`
So this would shift the bit you need in LSB position, and the & operator would mask the other bits. Example: `uint8_variable = 0110 1010
BIT_NEEDED=3
0110 1010 >> 3 = 0000 1101
0000 1101 & 0000 0001 = 0000 0001`

I think this should work properly. Remember to count bits from 0.

Comment: You also avoid sign shift problems by shifting right. Otherwise you must use an unsigned literal. eg `1u`.

Comment: @Jeroen3 I don't see how the sign is relevant considering that the masking is done afterwards.

Comment: @HarrySvensson It should not be functionally relevant, but some compilers (or static code analysis) will warn you about it.

Answer (score 2):

One of the things to look out for is the amount of CPU cycles required for shifting. Some processor have a barrel-shifters thus shifting by 1 or by 3,4,.. N takes the same time.

Micro-controllers often can shift only 1 position per clock cycle. Thus `>> 7` takes 7 clocks.

Therefore I often use:

```
new_pos = (old_pos & (1 << BIT_POSITION)) ? (1 << NEW_BIT_POSITION) : 0;
```

A second advantage is that your new bit position can be left or right of the old one. This code does not care about that whilst you otherwise have to think about shifting right or left.

Of course a small variant allows you to add bits to an existing variable:

```
new_pos |= (old_pos & (1 << BIT_POSITION)) ? (1 << NEW_BIT_POSITION) : 0;
```

Comment: Which MCU can shift only 1 position per cycle?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič AVRtiny/mega and PIC12/16 are two I know of the top of my head.

Comment: Migrate to ARM  and you'll have a much faster MCU, executing in one single cycle.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič PIC still smokes ARM for extreme low power applications. Will hopefully change in the future, but for now many of us are stuck with memory banks and the W register.

Comment: @Jon If your PIC needs 8 cycles to perform this, while an ARM can do it in 1 cycle, your PIC needs 8 times more power to perform the calculation. You have to look at the total power consumption over time, not on lowest peak use.

Comment: @Lundin very true, however I think that is one of the key points of this answer - that it doesn't take 8 cycles on a PIC if you code it this way. Marko questioned whether this mattered anymore, and I answered that there are still a number of popular architectures where it does. For how much longer? I don't know, but given how fast ARM is developing, I imagine my comment will be outdated in a couple more years.

Comment: @Jon I would rather imagine that your comment already went outdated 10-20 years ago or so. All the PIC-huggers tend to compare the current used by a 8 bit PIC at 8MHz vs an ARM at 80MHz. Number 1 is to compare them when running on the very same oscillator, number 2 is to compare them when executing the very same C code. For example when executing 16 or 32 bit arithmetic. You'll most likely find the PIC needs much more current than the ARM, if you take the respective cores as they were 10 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

> Update: One more question. I need to set a particular bit in a uint8
>   to a value X(not toggling the bit). eg: In 1100 0101, I need to set
>   bit 2 to X, without modifying the other bits - to obtain 1100 0X01. I
>   have been racking my brain, but I can't land on a straight forward
>   solution.

To achieve this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BIT_POSITION 2
#define SET_BIT 1
#define CLR_BIT 0


uint8_t setOrClearBit(uint8_t variable, uint8_t bit_position, uint8_t setOrClear)
{
    if(setOrClear) {
        variable |= (1<<bit_position); 
    }
    else {
        variable &= ~(1<<bit_position);
    }
    return variable;
}

uint8_t test = 0b11000001;
int main(void)
{
     printf("%d\n", setOrClearBit(test, BIT_POSITION, SET_BIT));
    printf("%d\n", setOrClearBit(test, BIT_POSITION, CLR_BIT));

}
```

Or if no conditionals required:

```
uint8_t setOrClearBit(uint8_t variable, uint8_t bit_position, uint8_t setOrClear)
{
    variable = (variable & ~(1<<bit_position)) | (setOrClear<<bit_position);
    return variable; 
}
```